# Images getting merged into single plot while saving plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-3.6

The code below is used for finding patterns from csv data.

Everything is working as expected, but at the end of the plotting, previous images are getting merged in to the latest plot is there any possibility to avoid this?

---

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from harmonic_functions import *
import uuid
import requests
import json


data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

data.time = pd.to_datetime(data.time,format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
data.index = data['time']
# data = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

price = data.close.copy()

err_allowed = 10.0/100

pnl = []
trade_dates=[]
correct_pats=0
pats=0

# plt.ion()

for i in range (100,len(price)):

    current_idx,current_pat,start,end = peak_detect(price.values[:i],order=7)

    XA = current_pat[1] - current_pat[0]
    AB = current_pat[2] - current_pat[1]
    BC = current_pat[3] - current_pat[2]
    CD = current_pat[4] - current_pat[3]

    moves = [XA,AB,BC,CD]

    gart = is_gartley(moves,err_allowed)
    butt = is_butterfly(moves,err_allowed)
    bat = is_bat(moves,err_allowed)
    crab = is_crab(moves,err_allowed)
    shark = is_shark(moves,err_allowed)
    trio = is_trio(moves,err_allowed)
    cyph = is_cyph(moves,err_allowed)
    three_dives = is_3dives(moves, err_allowed)
    fivezero = is_50(moves, err_allowed)
    altbat = is_altbat(moves, err_allowed)
    deepcrab = is_deepcrab(moves, err_allowed)
    dragon = is_dragon(moves, err_allowed)
    snorm = is_snorm(moves, err_allowed)

    harmonics = np.array([gart,butt,bat,crab,shark,trio,cyph,three_dives,fivezero,altbat,deepcrab,dragon,snorm])
    labels = ['Garterly','Butterfly','Bat','Crab','Shark','Trio','Cypher','3Dives','5Zero','AltBat','DeepCrab','Dragon','Snorm']


    if np.any(harmonics == 1) or np.any(harmonics == -1):
        for j in range (0,len(harmonics)):
            if harmonics[j] == 1 or harmonics[j]==-1:
                pats+=1
                sense = 'Bearish ' if harmonics[j]==-1 else 'Bullish '
                label = sense + labels[j] + ' found'
                print(label)

                plt.title(label)
                print(current_pat)
                plt.plot(np.arange(start,i+15),price.values[start:i+15])
                plt.scatter(current_idx,current_pat,c='r')
                print(current_pat)
                filename = str(uuid.uuid1())[:8]
                print(filename)
                plt.savefig(filename)
                plt.close(filename)
```

---

All my input data is listed here below. The plots are working for the 18th, but for the 19th, plots are inducing/merging with the plots for 18th as well, please see the attached image.

**Input data**

```
[time,open,high,low,close,volume
18.05.2020 09:15:00.000,9108,9138.7,9073.4,9075,543675
18.05.2020 09:17:00.000,9074.95,9089.4,9064.7,9087,303150
18.05.2020 09:19:00.000,9089,9094.75,9080.5,9082.3,199050
18.05.2020 09:21:00.000,9083.95,9083.95,9057,9063.15,270225
18.05.2020 09:23:00.000,9062.4,9072.65,9055,9063.85,130500
18.05.2020 09:25:00.000,9063.5,9067.7,9050.05,9056.45,193050
18.05.2020 09:27:00.000,9054.85,9065,9051,9064.7,122250
18.05.2020 09:29:00.000,9063.05,9068.8,9044,9048.1,272025
18.05.2020 09:31:00.000,9046.95,9053,9043.05,9048.1,128775
18.05.2020 09:33:00.000,9048.95,9048.95,9015.65,9023.15,349950
18.05.2020 09:35:00.000,9023.6,9024.75,8980,8980,474675
18.05.2020 09:37:00.000,8980.95,9001,8966.5,8996.05,372525
18.05.2020 09:39:00.000,8997.05,9000,8978.6,8986.35,175875
18.05.2020 09:41:00.000,8984.4,8989.7,8941.95,8944,315225
18.05.2020 09:43:00.000,8943.8,8952,8923.7,8925,359625
18.05.2020 09:45:00.000,8923.75,8925.1,8878.05,8897.25,527550
18.05.2020 09:47:00.000,8895.25,8919.95,8888.85,8915.75,300750
18.05.2020 09:49:00.000,8916.05,8944.2,8914,8935.55,284700
18.05.2020 09:51:00.000,8935.4,8937,8903.05,8918,272400
18.05.2020 09:53:00.000,8919.45,8926.65,8900.05,8913.6,154800
18.05.2020 09:55:00.000,8912.4,8923,8904.5,8919.8,121875
18.05.2020 09:57:00.000,8919.75,8932,8916.45,8931.6,113175
18.05.2020 09:59:00.000,8931.85,8935.45,8908.2,8913.4,136500
18.05.2020 10:01:00.000,8913.15,8940,8908.65,8935.35,196725
18.05.2020 10:03:00.000,8934.05,8939,8927,8930.4,151575
18.05.2020 10:05:00.000,8930.6,8947.05,8918,8924,202650
18.05.2020 10:07:00.000,8925.45,8940.1,8924,8934,141225
18.05.2020 10:09:00.000,8935.1,8945,8929.2,8942,101850
18.05.2020 10:11:00.000,8941.2,8946,8929.5,8943.3,112200
18.05.2020 10:13:00.000,8942.2,8949,8924.55,8927.5,129975
18.05.2020 10:15:00.000,8927.55,8935,8922,8922.5,76500
18.05.2020 10:17:00.000,8923.9,8926.25,8916,8921.35,122100
18.05.2020 10:19:00.000,8921.75,8934,8921.35,8928.2,71625
18.05.2020 10:21:00.000,8928.2,8934.7,8925.6,8932.45,42975
18.05.2020 10:23:00.000,8931.05,8935,8926.55,8933,40725
18.05.2020 10:25:00.000,8932.85,8942,8931.15,8933,44925
18.05.2020 10:27:00.000,8933,8939.85,8931.05,8933.6,36225
18.05.2020 10:29:00.000,8933.5,8936.75,8920.2,8921,68325
18.05.2020 10:31:00.000,8920.2,8923.8,8913.25,8919,75000
18.05.2020 10:33:00.000,8918.95,8921.25,8912.35,8916.6,81450
18.05.2020 10:35:00.000,8915,8918,8906,8906.6,92925
18.05.2020 10:37:00.000,8909.45,8924.5,8902.1,8916.85,105300
18.05.2020 10:39:00.000,8917.85,8920,8912,8914.25,36750
18.05.2020 10:41:00.000,8914.9,8917.3,8910.6,8916.95,35175
18.05.2020 10:43:00.000,8916,8920.35,8910.7,8913.75,48975
18.05.2020 10:45:00.000,8913.4,8913.4,8865.55,8866.15,410625
18.05.2020 10:47:00.000,8862.65,8879.8,8859.25,8879,194400
18.05.2020 10:49:00.000,8881.45,8881.45,8860,8872.35,136950
18.05.2020 10:51:00.000,8872.1,8878.7,8861.55,8868.05,83400
18.05.2020 10:53:00.000,8867.9,8876.95,8863.8,8869.4,90675
18.05.2020 10:55:00.000,8868,8870.55,8842.85,8856,208050
18.05.2020 10:57:00.000,8855,8858.65,8840,8858.15,131175
18.05.2020 10:59:00.000,8858.7,8859.05,8851,8853.6,81075
18.05.2020 11:01:00.000,8855,8855,8837.45,8854.35,117975
18.05.2020 11:03:00.000,8854.6,8862.7,8851.55,8860,76200
18.05.2020 11:05:00.000,8861.7,8867.5,8853.05,8865.75,75450
18.05.2020 11:07:00.000,8865,8869.35,8855.35,8856.25,71850
18.05.2020 11:09:00.000,8860.95,8861.6,8831,8836.95,130800
18.05.2020 11:11:00.000,8835.7,8848.45,8834,8841.4,103800
18.05.2020 11:13:00.000,8844,8855,8842.8,8853.85,65700
18.05.2020 11:15:00.000,8852.95,8853.85,8844,8852,55275
18.05.2020 11:17:00.000,8852,8854.85,8844.35,8847.9,61275
18.05.2020 11:19:00.000,8847.5,8850.75,8835.05,8840,85350
18.05.2020 11:21:00.000,8839,8843.25,8832,8832,70275
18.05.2020 11:23:00.000,8832,8839,8822.85,8827.35,155925
18.05.2020 11:25:00.000,8827.7,8833.9,8822.1,8826,82725
18.05.2020 11:27:00.000,8826,8838.65,8825,8835,63225
18.05.2020 11:29:00.000,8834.15,8845.35,8834.15,8837.9,97125
18.05.2020 11:31:00.000,8840.95,8853.55,8836,8848.15,94725
18.05.2020 11:33:00.000,8849.95,8858.2,8846.7,8852.2,104550
18.05.2020 11:35:00.000,8853.45,8865.95,8851.95,8853.65,143475
18.05.2020 11:37:00.000,8855,8868.4,8850.05,8863.85,79800
18.05.2020 11:39:00.000,8862.05,8863,8851.3,8851.4,51375
18.05.2020 11:41:00.000,8851.1,8863.6,8848.15,8861.55,57900
18.05.2020 11:43:00.000,8863.9,8868.45,8858,8859.3,61875
18.05.2020 11:45:00.000,8858.15,8873.4,8855,8864.15,80925
18.05.2020 11:47:00.000,8864.5,8866,8857.1,8866,51375
18.05.2020 11:49:00.000,8866.4,8868,8859.85,8861.95,37500
18.05.2020 11:51:00.000,8861.95,8862.55,8856.05,8862.55,37200
18.05.2020 11:53:00.000,8863,8879.25,8860.5,8875.8,114300
18.05.2020 11:55:00.000,8873.1,8874.8,8867,8870.9,56100
18.05.2020 11:57:00.000,8865.6,8871,8862.9,8862.9,37275
18.05.2020 11:59:00.000,8862.9,8874.9,8862.75,8871,33000
18.05.2020 12:01:00.000,8870.5,8879,8870.2,8872.8,74475
18.05.2020 12:03:00.000,8874,8881,8869,8872.9,84975
18.05.2020 12:05:00.000,8872,8883.15,8871.05,8879.4,68925
18.05.2020 12:07:00.000,8879.25,8882,8871.55,8873,36750
18.05.2020 12:09:00.000,8872,8874.95,8865.25,8868.15,64050
18.05.2020 12:11:00.000,8868.15,8869.3,8860.9,8861,63150
18.05.2020 12:13:00.000,8861,8866,8858.45,8864.65,45750
18.05.2020 12:15:00.000,8864.65,8864.65,8858,8861.9,58500
18.05.2020 12:17:00.000,8864.45,8871.35,8861,8870,36975
18.05.2020 12:19:00.000,8872,8872,8860.05,8861.95,26475
18.05.2020 12:21:00.000,8861.95,8865.65,8858,8859.2,29475
18.05.2020 12:23:00.000,8859.4,8869,8857.25,8863.1,35625
18.05.2020 12:25:00.000,8863.1,8865,8858.05,8863.75,14550
18.05.2020 12:27:00.000,8863.75,8872.5,8860.65,8866.85,48825
18.05.2020 12:29:00.000,8865.55,8875.65,8863.65,8869.9,64725
18.05.2020 12:31:00.000,8871.05,8878.75,8868.1,8878,50700
18.05.2020 12:33:00.000,8876.4,8897,8875.3,8892.55,216225
18.05.2020 12:35:00.000,8893.75,8897.6,8887,8887.2,116925
18.05.2020 12:37:00.000,8888,8890.25,8881.35,8884.1,90675
18.05.2020 12:39:00.000,8885.95,8895,8884.05,8894.55,75525
18.05.2020 12:41:00.000,8894.4,8895,8883.15,8886,59400
18.05.2020 12:43:00.000,8884.45,8897.8,8882,8897.8,47400
18.05.2020 12:45:00.000,8896.9,8913.3,8894.1,8902.3,222000
18.05.2020 12:47:00.000,8902.2,8906.15,8892,8895.95,71100
18.05.2020 12:49:00.000,8895.75,8897.95,8883.05,8886.15,63975
18.05.2020 12:51:00.000,8886.75,8893,8884,8888.5,75300
18.05.2020 12:53:00.000,8888.95,8896,8886.15,8890.05,44775
18.05.2020 12:55:00.000,8889.9,8896,8886,8888.8,33825
18.05.2020 12:57:00.000,8887.35,8890,8876.65,8883,69075
18.05.2020 12:59:00.000,8884,8886.4,8880,8884.45,45825
18.05.2020 13:01:00.000,8884.45,8892,8882.1,8891.55,49950
18.05.2020 13:03:00.000,8890,8891.55,8882.25,8887.2,27750
18.05.2020 13:05:00.000,8887.2,8890.95,8866.3,8868.45,77100
18.05.2020 13:07:00.000,8866.35,8875,8866.35,8873.7,66075
18.05.2020 13:09:00.000,8873.7,8873.7,8864.1,8870.05,66225
18.05.2020 13:11:00.000,8870.05,8872.45,8866.5,8868.6,43425
18.05.2020 13:13:00.000,8868.6,8878.05,8866.4,8876.35,58800
18.05.2020 13:15:00.000,8878.1,8878.45,8862,8866,52725
18.05.2020 13:17:00.000,8863.55,8870,8861.6,8867.05,49125
18.05.2020 13:19:00.000,8869,8872.65,8866,8869.5,53850
18.05.2020 13:21:00.000,8868.8,8872.75,8858.75,8858.75,82275
18.05.2020 13:23:00.000,8858,8865.95,8858,8860.55,58050
18.05.2020 13:25:00.000,8860.1,8865.55,8858.2,8858.2,51450
18.05.2020 13:27:00.000,8858.5,8860,8844.75,8847,179025
18.05.2020 13:29:00.000,8848.2,8851.5,8825,8832.7,213600
18.05.2020 13:31:00.000,8832.45,8845.95,8827,8840.7,125775
18.05.2020 13:33:00.000,8842.45,8848.8,8835.95,8847.3,73050
18.05.2020 13:35:00.000,8847,8865.8,8846,8865.8,119625
18.05.2020 13:37:00.000,8865.65,8867.8,8855,8858.4,45675
18.05.2020 13:39:00.000,8858.65,8865,8853,8856,51375
18.05.2020 13:41:00.000,8857.9,8862.95,8854,8855.6,42300
18.05.2020 13:43:00.000,8855.6,8858.85,8848.25,8853.4,50475
18.05.2020 13:45:00.000,8852.25,8877.75,8852.25,8877.75,82275
18.05.2020 13:47:00.000,8876.1,8897,8874.85,8884.95,210675
18.05.2020 13:49:00.000,8884.55,8903,8883.25,8901.75,130125
18.05.2020 13:51:00.000,8901.75,8901.75,8882,8882.7,70950
18.05.2020 13:53:00.000,8882.45,8895,8880,8893.05,71475
18.05.2020 13:55:00.000,8893,8914.5,8893,8894.95,217200
18.05.2020 13:57:00.000,8893.1,8911,8893.1,8904,97275
18.05.2020 13:59:00.000,8901.85,8906.55,8896.3,8896.3,89100
18.05.2020 14:01:00.000,8896.3,8896.3,8882.55,8885.85,99675
18.05.2020 14:03:00.000,8888.05,8890,8875.65,8885,83775
18.05.2020 14:05:00.000,8886.5,8895.1,8882,8886.45,54150
18.05.2020 14:07:00.000,8885.2,8902.55,8883,8897,68325
18.05.2020 14:09:00.000,8898.1,8904.55,8892.75,8902.8,51525
18.05.2020 14:11:00.000,8904.4,8917,8900,8905.9,153075
18.05.2020 14:13:00.000,8906.9,8908,8894.4,8894.4,74775
18.05.2020 14:15:00.000,8896,8904.5,8890,8891.15,67350
18.05.2020 14:17:00.000,8890,8891.15,8862.25,8868.65,192675
18.05.2020 14:19:00.000,8868.5,8880.55,8864.8,8876,89400
18.05.2020 14:21:00.000,8876,8879,8871.1,8875,41400
18.05.2020 14:23:00.000,8875,8889,8870.45,8884.65,63150
18.05.2020 14:25:00.000,8885,8889,8878.6,8883,52275
18.05.2020 14:27:00.000,8883,8899,8883,8893.85,74025
18.05.2020 14:29:00.000,8893.7,8896,8882.1,8883,65175
18.05.2020 14:31:00.000,8882.55,8897,8882.55,8891.1,75900
18.05.2020 14:33:00.000,8891.7,8893,8874.75,8876.1,81300
18.05.2020 14:35:00.000,8875.85,8875.85,8865.4,8868.1,151800
18.05.2020 14:37:00.000,8868.05,8874.85,8863.65,8869.75,78300
18.05.2020 14:39:00.000,8869.75,8885,8868.25,8883.8,62100
18.05.2020 14:41:00.000,8883.05,8884.05,8871.2,8878.55,37725
18.05.2020 14:43:00.000,8878.55,8878.55,8865.6,8869,45825
18.05.2020 14:45:00.000,8869,8869.4,8845.55,8859.5,207300
18.05.2020 14:47:00.000,8859,8868,8852.05,8863.1,119550
18.05.2020 14:49:00.000,8863.75,8866.75,8857.3,8860.9,43275
18.05.2020 14:51:00.000,8860.9,8868,8852.2,8868,69825
18.05.2020 14:53:00.000,8868,8879.65,8866.1,8866.1,90375
18.05.2020 14:55:00.000,8867.5,8870.6,8858,8859.45,55050
18.05.2020 14:57:00.000,8859.45,8864,8852.85,8856,80100
18.05.2020 14:59:00.000,8856,8860,8843.3,8845,126375
18.05.2020 15:01:00.000,8845,8845,8820.6,8826.1,266775
18.05.2020 15:03:00.000,8825,8835,8819.05,8825.5,143325
18.05.2020 15:05:00.000,8825.45,8825.45,8811.05,8821.75,185475
18.05.2020 15:07:00.000,8821.7,8832.85,8820.35,8832.85,146400
18.05.2020 15:09:00.000,8833,8835,8817.05,8817.85,145050
18.05.2020 15:11:00.000,8818,8826.1,8813.35,8826.1,186600
18.05.2020 15:13:00.000,8824.7,8828.65,8817.15,8826,122325
18.05.2020 15:15:00.000,8828,8829.7,8817.15,8818.45,142275
18.05.2020 15:17:00.000,8818.4,8823.15,8813.55,8823.15,156225
18.05.2020 15:19:00.000,8824,8829.95,8820.55,8826.2,207900
18.05.2020 15:21:00.000,8826.6,8830,8820.15,8824.55,164775
18.05.2020 15:23:00.000,8824.55,8832.7,8824.55,8832.7,175725
18.05.2020 15:25:00.000,8832,8832.25,8825.15,8826.7,208650
18.05.2020 15:27:00.000,8827.45,8829.8,8825.3,8829.2,143850
18.05.2020 15:29:00.000,8829.35,8830.75,8826.8,8829.5,90750
19.05.2020 09:15:00.000,8971,8971,8885.5,8888.3,750225
19.05.2020 09:17:00.000,8889.95,8926.65,8889.05,8922.05,425550
19.05.2020 09:19:00.000,8921.85,8947,8921.35,8941.45,390975
19.05.2020 09:21:00.000,8939.7,8945,8923,8930.8,295350
19.05.2020 09:23:00.000,8930,8941,8908.2,8911.95,280425
19.05.2020 09:25:00.000,8910.65,8913.5,8895.3,8897.4,294750
19.05.2020 09:27:00.000,8897.15,8910,8889.45,8890.7,222525
19.05.2020 09:29:00.000,8891.15,8901.4,8860.2,8860.2,325875
19.05.2020 09:31:00.000,8860.1,8879.1,8860.1,8871.65,237000
19.05.2020 09:33:00.000,8869.15,8888,8861.5,8887.05,224175
19.05.2020 09:35:00.000,8887.55,8906.2,8887,8898.25,233775
19.05.2020 09:37:00.000,8900,8903.75,8888.85,8897.55,143925
19.05.2020 09:39:00.000,8898,8931.7,8898,8923,315675
19.05.2020 09:41:00.000,8920.6,8945.85,8920.05,8936.1,260700
19.05.2020 09:43:00.000,8936.55,8942.75,8928.9,8932.2,146175
19.05.2020 09:45:00.000,8934.25,8956.3,8934,8953.15,298125
19.05.2020 09:47:00.000,8953.85,8955,8935.2,8942.65,142350
19.05.2020 09:49:00.000,8942,8978.25,8940,8968,404325
19.05.2020 09:51:00.000,8967.95,8975.45,8962.75,8962.75,208125
19.05.2020 09:53:00.000,8962.55,8974.65,8951.1,8974.65,153525
19.05.2020 09:55:00.000,8976.25,8978,8961.35,8964.75,121650
19.05.2020 09:57:00.000,8964.1,8972.25,8961.6,8964.1,103950
19.05.2020 09:59:00.000,8966,8967.85,8953.4,8955.1,100425
19.05.2020 10:01:00.000,8956.2,8963.1,8946.1,8963.1,128100
19.05.2020 10:03:00.000,8962.3,8988,8962.1,8986.1,293550
19.05.2020 10:05:00.000,8987.6,8992.2,8978,8979.15,185100
19.05.2020 10:07:00.000,8980.85,8985.05,8974.1,8979.2,83475
19.05.2020 10:09:00.000,8982,8987.9,8979,8983.05,107400
19.05.2020 10:11:00.000,8982.8,8985.3,8969.8,8971.8,102825
19.05.2020 10:13:00.000,8972.45,8979.25,8970.7,8971.6,65550
19.05.2020 10:15:00.000,8971.75,8993,8970,8991.65,145050
19.05.2020 10:17:00.000,8991.6,9000,8987.85,8998.25,194850
19.05.2020 10:19:00.000,8999,9009.6,8995,9000,252450
19.05.2020 10:21:00.000,9000.45,9002.25,8992,8993.7,102600
19.05.2020 10:23:00.000,8994.05,8998,8990.45,8996.6,112500
19.05.2020 10:25:00.000,8997,9024,8996.4,9013,311775
19.05.2020 10:27:00.000,9014.85,9028.8,9013.65,9028.1,170250
19.05.2020 10:29:00.000,9027.8,9029.85,9012,9013.7,141900
19.05.2020 10:31:00.000,9013.7,9024.65,9012.05,9017.05,114600
19.05.2020 10:33:00.000,9017.9,9025,9015.7,9019.9,72525
19.05.2020 10:35:00.000,9021.05,9034.5,9020.8,9026.55,161100
19.05.2020 10:37:00.000,9025.55,9027,9012.85,9014.85,142275
19.05.2020 10:39:00.000,9015.05,9019.4,9008.5,9017.85,105525
19.05.2020 10:41:00.000,9018.9,9019.65,9012.05,9016.05,58050
19.05.2020 10:43:00.000,9016.05,9027.7,9014.1,9023.5,94800
19.05.2020 10:45:00.000,9024.1,9024.1,9011.05,9012.9,86100
19.05.2020 10:47:00.000,9013.65,9029,9004,9023.45,120825
19.05.2020 10:49:00.000,9022,9033.05,9021.2,9030,91875
19.05.2020 10:51:00.000,9030.9,9033.1,9021.25,9023.05,74850
19.05.2020 10:53:00.000,9023.1,9031.65,9021,9021.85,66375
19.05.2020 10:55:00.000,9020.75,9023.35,9010.55,9010.55,90075
19.05.2020 10:57:00.000,9010,9030,9009.9,9025,100425
19.05.2020 10:59:00.000,9025.9,9032,9022.3,9023.65,68100
19.05.2020 11:01:00.000,9023,9023.65,9012.15,9014.3,72225
19.05.2020 11:03:00.000,9012.9,9016,8996.55,9002.25,160425
19.05.2020 11:05:00.000,9002.5,9002.5,8973,8975.3,273300
19.05.2020 11:07:00.000,8975.85,8984.25,8966.5,8968.1,181800
19.05.2020 11:09:00.000,8969.45,8981.35,8969.45,8974.9,123750
19.05.2020 11:11:00.000,8975.05,8979.9,8958.3,8960.65,162675
19.05.2020 11:13:00.000,8960.8,8966.6,8953.7,8964.55,181125
19.05.2020 11:15:00.000,8967.7,8976,8960,8975,114300
19.05.2020 11:17:00.000,8974.6,8976,8952.3,8952.3,99825
19.05.2020 11:19:00.000,8950.85,8956.7,8935.65,8955.05,255225
19.05.2020 11:21:00.000,8955.2,8957.8,8946,8948,81825
19.05.2020 11:23:00.000,8949.85,8962.9,8947.65,8960.4,68025
19.05.2020 11:25:00.000,8961,8971.55,8960.1,8968.7,89700
19.05.2020 11:27:00.000,8966.6,8972.9,8960,8960.2,56700
19.05.2020 11:29:00.000,8960,8960.2,8947.35,8947.35,73050
19.05.2020 11:31:00.000,8948.75,8959.3,8947.6,8957.05,54600
19.05.2020 11:33:00.000,8961,8972.35,8958.9,8965.2,73425
19.05.2020 11:35:00.000,8963.25,8966.15,8955.05,8966,30675
19.05.2020 11:37:00.000,8967.4,8974.4,8965,8971,48825
19.05.2020 11:39:00.000,8970.1,8983.95,8967.25,8983.95,101250
19.05.2020 11:41:00.000,8983.35,8984.4,8975.25,8979.9,69525
19.05.2020 11:43:00.000,8979.9,8986.3,8977.1,8980.1,87600
19.05.2020 11:45:00.000,8981.8,8982,8971.4,8979.45,49050
19.05.2020 11:47:00.000,8979.45,8992.15,8979.45,8992.15,93075
19.05.2020 11:49:00.000,8992.7,8992.7,8983.2,8987.7,64875
19.05.2020 11:51:00.000,8987.25,8990,8980.25,8981,40200
19.05.2020 11:53:00.000,8981,8990,8980.7,8987.85,36675
19.05.2020 11:55:00.000,8986.6,8999.95,8986.6,8995.85,91350
19.05.2020 11:57:00.000,8992.65,9005.95,8992.5,9001.1,97425
19.05.2020 11:59:00.000,9000.5,9003.3,8995,8995.15,50700
19.05.2020 12:01:00.000,8995.95,9004,8991.4,9002.35,65625
19.05.2020 12:03:00.000,9000.35,9004,8998.05,9001,80250
19.05.2020 12:05:00.000,9001,9002,8990.5,8992.7,71400
19.05.2020 12:07:00.000,8993.45,8994.15,8985,8985,81000
19.05.2020 12:09:00.000,8985.05,8989.35,8982.5,8982.5,50100
19.05.2020 12:11:00.000,8982.5,8984.6,8977,8980.55,58500
19.05.2020 12:13:00.000,8980.55,8991.45,8978,8991.45,51675
19.05.2020 12:15:00.000,8990.35,8991.5,8981.45,8983.8,54075
19.05.2020 12:17:00.000,8983.8,8989.9,8980,8989.65,23700
19.05.2020 12:19:00.000,8987.05,9000.1,8987.05,8996,68100
19.05.2020 12:21:00.000,8996.5,9011,8995,9008.4,105750
19.05.2020 12:23:00.000,9008.45,9009.05,9000,9000.15,77700
19.05.2020 12:25:00.000,9000.4,9003.1,8995,9000,63900
19.05.2020 12:27:00.000,9000,9010,9000,9006.1,66675
19.05.2020 12:29:00.000,9007.6,9007.6,8992,8992.5,68175
19.05.2020 12:31:00.000,8992.5,8994.4,8984.15,8987.7,75525
19.05.2020 12:33:00.000,8987.1,8989.95,8985,8985.35,53475
19.05.2020 12:35:00.000,8984,8986.3,8974.05,8983,116025
19.05.2020 12:37:00.000,8983,8987,8980,8984,43275
19.05.2020 12:39:00.000,8984.55,8984.55,8970,8972.1,106125
19.05.2020 12:41:00.000,8971.2,8981.05,8967.4,8980.95,60075
19.05.2020 12:43:00.000,8980.9,8983.4,8970,8971.75,37650
19.05.2020 12:45:00.000,8973,8982.95,8970.05,8982.95,42150
19.05.2020 12:47:00.000,8983,8992.8,8981.65,8989,73050
19.05.2020 12:49:00.000,8989,8991.9,8982,8985.55,27900
19.05.2020 12:51:00.000,8984.15,8991.4,8980.5,8986.35,27825
19.05.2020 12:53:00.000,8986.25,8986.25,8969,8970.5,68550
19.05.2020 12:55:00.000,8969.9,8972.1,8956.25,8967.45,133800
19.05.2020 12:57:00.000,8965.4,8970,8960,8962.2,58575
19.05.2020 12:59:00.000,8962.2,8962.2,8946,8948,134775
19.05.2020 13:01:00.000,8948.8,8958,8942.25,8956.8,110325
19.05.2020 13:03:00.000,8957.3,8960,8949,8949,54450
19.05.2020 13:05:00.000,8948.25,8950.1,8917.25,8920.9,294300
19.05.2020 13:07:00.000,8922.8,8932,8922.8,8930.5,132900
19.05.2020 13:09:00.000,8931,8935,8915,8919.3,103800
19.05.2020 13:11:00.000,8917.95,8938,8917,8935.5,93300
19.05.2020 13:13:00.000,8933,8942.9,8932,8939.25,82050
19.05.2020 13:15:00.000,8939,8948,8932.2,8945.35,73950
19.05.2020 13:17:00.000,8945,8950,8940,8945,72900
19.05.2020 13:19:00.000,8946,8960,8945,8949.7,77700
19.05.2020 13:21:00.000,8948.1,8954.3,8942.4,8942.4,41250
19.05.2020 13:23:00.000,8942.4,8943.9,8928.9,8932.6,76500
19.05.2020 13:25:00.000,8932.55,8937,8927.85,8933,68625
19.05.2020 13:27:00.000,8933,8945,8932.6,8937,40125
19.05.2020 13:29:00.000,8936.45,8939.85,8927.55,8934.6,40950
19.05.2020 13:31:00.000,8934.6,8946.55,8934.6,8938.15,43725
19.05.2020 13:33:00.000,8938.95,8938.95,8912,8913.75,114900
19.05.2020 13:35:00.000,8913.55,8921.15,8902.5,8911.9,195075
19.05.2020 13:37:00.000,8910.1,8914.4,8895.05,8896.8,216300
19.05.2020 13:39:00.000,8896,8906,8888.85,8894.65,181275
19.05.2020 13:41:00.000,8896,8900,8877.1,8879.3,180000
19.05.2020 13:43:00.000,8879.85,8902.95,8875.2,8900.7,150450
19.05.2020 13:45:00.000,8897.7,8900.7,8877.9,8880,131925
19.05.2020 13:47:00.000,8881,8888,8879.5,8887.4,78825
19.05.2020 13:49:00.000,8886.1,8913.9,8886.1,8903.05,134025
19.05.2020 13:51:00.000,8903.75,8903.75,8880.05,8880.05,84600
19.05.2020 13:53:00.000,8881.3,8882.7,8866.55,8872,145275
19.05.2020 13:55:00.000,8870.6,8878.3,8859.05,8872,161775
19.05.2020 13:57:00.000,8870,8879,8861.75,8875.25,88575
19.05.2020 13:59:00.000,8875.1,8893.55,8874,8893.15,109200
19.05.2020 14:01:00.000,8893.65,8893.65,8877.45,8879,71475
19.05.2020 14:03:00.000,8879.7,8889.85,8873.15,8886.45,59250
19.05.2020 14:05:00.000,8888.1,8889,8867,8870.25,95850
19.05.2020 14:07:00.000,8869.15,8884.9,8865.1,8879,89475
19.05.2020 14:09:00.000,8878.4,8881.05,8863,8863.25,90450
19.05.2020 14:11:00.000,8863,8868.3,8852.6,8865,182475
19.05.2020 14:13:00.000,8867.85,8882,8865,8875.1,136650
19.05.2020 14:15:00.000,8874.1,8895.55,8868,8893.5,132450
19.05.2020 14:17:00.000,8893.7,8898.65,8887,8898.65,132000
19.05.2020 14:19:00.000,8897.95,8923,8897.95,8915.95,248550
19.05.2020 14:21:00.000,8915.05,8917.15,8895.6,8897.55,124500
19.05.2020 14:23:00.000,8897.85,8914.8,8895.6,8914.1,114375
19.05.2020 14:25:00.000,8910.05,8912.95,8905,8906.8,66000
19.05.2020 14:27:00.000,8906.8,8918.7,8902.15,8915.5,76725
19.05.2020 14:29:00.000,8914,8920,8900,8901.6,74250
19.05.2020 14:31:00.000,8901.9,8908.15,8890.15,8894,82575
19.05.2020 14:33:00.000,8894.65,8904.5,8888,8889.9,74025
19.05.2020 14:35:00.000,8890.2,8900.1,8888.1,8899.6,41325
19.05.2020 14:37:00.000,8899.6,8909.45,8897.45,8905,72000
19.05.2020 14:39:00.000,8904.05,8905,8883.35,8883.55,68475
19.05.2020 14:41:00.000,8884,8888.15,8881.6,8884.6,79050
19.05.2020 14:43:00.000,8884.75,8898.1,8884.35,8895.25,67425
19.05.2020 14:45:00.000,8895.25,8900,8890.05,8892.9,36450
19.05.2020 14:47:00.000,8893,8898.7,8883.45,8896.95,54900
19.05.2020 14:49:00.000,8897,8907.7,8890,8890,88650
19.05.2020 14:51:00.000,8890,8899.95,8885,8890.85,89250
19.05.2020 14:53:00.000,8890.85,8894.3,8885.4,8888.15,62400
19.05.2020 14:55:00.000,8887.05,8887.2,8865.9,8868,143175
19.05.2020 14:57:00.000,8868,8880.3,8865.55,8880.3,69225
19.05.2020 14:59:00.000,8880.25,8883.2,8860.45,8863.3,125100
19.05.2020 15:01:00.000,8863.55,8880.9,8863.55,8880,103725
19.05.2020 15:03:00.000,8878.2,8887.65,8878,8887.65,102975
19.05.2020 15:05:00.000,8887.25,8887.3,8876.8,8876.8,48825
19.05.2020 15:07:00.000,8876.7,8879.6,8873,8878,59100
19.05.2020 15:09:00.000,8878.05,8884,8874.05,8875,90300
19.05.2020 15:11:00.000,8875,8884.2,8874.05,8883.45,75375
19.05.2020 15:13:00.000,8883.45,8895,8883,8888.7,98175
19.05.2020 15:15:00.000,8888.9,8892,8881,8886.05,96900
19.05.2020 15:17:00.000,8885.3,8889,8883,8886,63450
19.05.2020 15:19:00.000,8886,8893.5,8884.75,8890.05,83550
19.05.2020 15:21:00.000,8889.8,8894.6,8884.6,8887.9,95475
19.05.2020 15:23:00.000,8887.9,8893.9,8886.65,8892.9,91725
19.05.2020 15:25:00.000,8892.05,8893,8887.5,8889.65,91125
19.05.2020 15:27:00.000,8889.9,8891.85,8888.65,8890.25,112050
19.05.2020 15:29:00.000,8891.1,8892.85,8890,8891,53625][1]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i got it corrected by adding  `plt.clf()`